# What is this string of text that looks like a URL for?

Tags: mysql, heroku

To be more precise why does it have this URL like form?  It is used in my heroku appp my parsing out the host/username/passowrd/database which I use.  But why does it look like a URL address.

Is `mysql` a protocol?  I thought it was just a database or a command line executable in some cases.

I have found no where that I can use this URL like form that points to my database.

Even apps like sequel pro which are used to connect to mysql seem to have no use for it.

```
mysql://b77eeb5dd82foo:10d04foo@us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net/heroku_37a39aa6115afoo?reconnect=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [Data Source Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name) (DSN). As stated in the wiki

> Software (e.g., Crystal Reports, Microsoft Excel, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby) users can submit CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) queries to a data source by establishing a connection to the DSN.

The format is

```
<driver>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>?<params>
```

- `mysql:` means it's a MySQL database
- `b77eeb5dd82foo:10d04foo` is the username and password
- `us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net` is the server name
- `heroku_37a39aa6115afoo` is the database name
- `reconnect=true` is a parameter telling the driver to reconnect automatically when necessary

Most of the fields are optional; the port number is omitted from your DSN, so it uses the default (`3306` for MySQL).

Comment: nice breakdown but where would I actually use this? ... as I stated in my Q, I already know how to break this down and ue it log in to a database but why does it have this form ...

Comment: Many database applications and APIs use DSNs as the way to tell them where the database is.

Comment: oddly sequel pro ( which is a database application ) does not use this ... which one does ?

Comment: I used a DSN yesterday when configuring a data source in PhpStorm, an IDE.

Comment: well I think the :// is confusing b.c. normally what precedes this would be a protocol - `http, https, ftp, git` ... etc.  In this case it is just a descriptive string ... correct ?

Comment: The thing before `:` in URIs is called a "scheme". It's not always a protocol, it can be things like `mailto:` and `javascript:`. But DSNs aren't URIs, they just use a similar structure.

Comment: I said `normally precedes`.  If you want to be technical it can be a `scheme` or a `driver`, but this is confusing as the name `driver` is used by PDO to describe the `<database>;<host>` string which is extracted from the DSN ... it's a cluster f*** of words ...

Comment: The point is that this is NOT a URL. So it doesn't have to use the same terminology.

Comment: It's like a car with chassis and wheels and an oven in the middles instead of an actual car ... Not a car though.  Just has wheels a chassis and an oven.  I'm going to put a patent on that.  IPO time!